Q1 2024 but 1H 2024. Why?
To my knowledge:

one typically writes Q1 2024 and not 1Q 2024 to designate the first quarter of 2024 (example).
one typically writes 1H 2024 and not H1 2024 to designate the first half of 2024 (example).

Why don't we instead write consistently write 1H and 1Q, or H1 and Q1?

To address some comments:

Regarding the use of 1H, I see many results on Google  for "1H 2024": https://i.sstatic.net/gpuzLoIz.png, https://i.sstatic.net/f5g9sUK6.png, etc.
Knowing the origin may help learning. In this case, knowing whether to use 1H or H1 (which confuses me). Hence posting on https://ell.stackexchange.com/.


Nobody typically writes anything "to designate the first half of 2024". But the question is meaningless anyway. Why do Americans write month/day/year? The United States has a rather unique way of writing the date that is imitated in very few other countries (although Canada and Belize do also use the form). In America, the date is formally written in month/day/year form

@FumbleFingers  "Why do Americans write month/day/year?" is a valid question too. E.g., see https://iso.mit.edu/americanisms/date-format-in-the-united-states/#:~:text=One%20of%20the%20hypotheses%20is,been%20that%20way%20ever%20since.

I agree with @FumbleFingers. But credit to the questioner for providing links to the examples that have inspired the question. To me, Q1-Q4 have an accounting flavour. For example, you might see them as column headers in an Excel spreadsheet. Half years? Not so sure.

I'm not sure that these quarters and halves have much standardization. Months, days, hours, and minutes are much more common, to the point that they have recognized localized patterns.

Windows Update uses 23H1, 23H2, etc.

Thanks, I welcome answers contradicting the question's premises.

At work '2024-2025 week 1' was the one which contained April 1st and we commonly write '24-25/W1' in finance plans or records.

It may exist, but I've never seen 1H or H1 anywhere. If half a year is indicated then probably "Q1 & 2" or "Q1 & Q2" are more common. This also allows for "Q2 & 3" and similar.

Your example for "1H" seems to be a one-off. Chambers has Q as an abbreviation for Quarter but not H for Half. This is certainly not typical, and your example seems to be marketing content, which is never a reliable source.

Knowing the origin of something like this is not really germane to learning to speak and write in English.

@TimR I disagree, knowing the origin may help learning. In this case, knowing whether to use 1H or H1.

@FranckDernoncourt  I've never ever seen it used before.   Something like this is going to specified in the style sheet of the journal or online publication.  It's not at all comparable to US date format, which is something most people see almost every day of their lives.

@TimR Thanks, I see many results on Google  for "1H 2024": https://i.sstatic.net/gpuzLoIz.png, https://i.sstatic.net/f5g9sUK6.png, etc.

@FranckDernoncourt It's a specialized format which, I would venture to say, 9 out of 10 people will be totally clueless about.

@TimR agreed. Adding jargon tag.

This question belongs to a different site, it isn't a language problem that learners will be interested in  or find useful in order to improve their language skills.

@Mari-LouA As a language learner, understanding the etymology facilitates my learning.

Do you know what etymology is? It is tracing the history of a word or expression. There's no etymology involved in 1H 1Q because they are not words.  They are jargon, symbols and abbreviations for work/information purposes.

@Mari-LouA How to designate the study of the origin of an acronym?.  As a language learner, understanding how an acronym was chosen facilitates my learning.

oh, please it's like saying what is the etymology of L1 and L2 or B2 and C2, or "1 to 1", the symbols and numbers e.g. 1H represent words, ideas, cardinal and ordinal numbers. The etymology lies with  the number "one" or "Quarter", how does that help you with knowing which order the letter and number go? It's mere convention, and it does nothing to help  learners' language skills. It's just a bit of trivia. It should have been asked maybe on SuperUser.

@Mari-LouA sometimes there's a reason behind a conventions. Understanding the reason helps learn faster.

Sometimes there is a reason but when 1h  stands for "one hour" nine times out of ten, what will you have learnt? It is true that it can represent multiple things to multiple people but the majority have settled on h = hour, height, or hospital. There is no etymology for "1 H".  There are questions asking about the origin of expressions, fixed phrases and initialisms such as IOU, YOLO, or BRB, the latter carry definitely more meaning whereas LASER is a "word", and  it has a fascinating history.

@Mari-LouA https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/354480/3023 explains the logic for H1


Although almost all search results for "1H" are as an abbreviation for hour, I found one reference to support this notion: The Wikipedia article for "1H" lists "1H Year, 1st half of year."
Sometimes there is no satisfactory answer when we look at two things that look comparable and ask why they don't behave the same. We have to ultimately just be observers and observe that they don't. Any explanation would have to be a guess, but my guess would be that since these usages are not that common, they have simply evolved however they happen to evolve, independently.
While "Q1, Q2" etc. are common enough in the business world, the abbreviations for half a year are not at all common, as far as I can tell. Many contexts that divide a year into two parts speak of "semesters" instead. I'm not sure there's enough data to even make any claims about what's "typical" usage here.
Perhaps the burden is on "Q1" to explain itself: Since we normally say "first quarter," why did it not become "1Q"? Thinking to myself, I'm not sure whether I've ever heard "quarter one," but searching lightly for it yields no meaningful results in Google Books and few on the internet at large. I'm sure that there would be any better answer to that question either than "just because."
You mention in a comment "knowing whether to use 1H or H1." I would strongly advise using neither, and simply writing out "first half of the year." I would have no idea what either abbreviation meant if I encountered them, and even "Q1" is worth expanding outside of the context of business memos.


Oh I do think the 3Q 2024 style is common enough. Examples

I personally use Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 and H1, H2. So I think you can use either.
I can see why you might want to say 1H because it's the First Half, but to me, H1 means "Half 1" just like Q1 means "Quarter 1."

I eventually found that H1 is very common too (example 1, example 2). I believe the use of Q1 and H1 is similar to ISO-8601's spirit (most important info comes first) and readability (2024H1 vs. 20241H). There is however no  standards for Qs and Hs formatting.
