How to designate the study of the origin of an acronym?
Etymology is

the study of the origin of words and the way in which their meanings have changed throughout history.

How to designate the study of the origin of an acronym?

An acronym's meaning doesn't evolve in the way the meaning of a word does. It's a form of name representation, not an item in  speakers' vocabularies. Finding out what an acronym stands for is hardly worthy of the name "study".

@TimR how would you call it?

I wouldn't bother to give it a name.

@TimR how would you rephrase  "How to designate the study of the origin of an acronym?"

I don't consider it a study. I looked up the meaning of the acronym on the internet.  It's a simple lookup on a list of acronyms somewhere.

And there, the word "meaning" is used loosely. What is meant is "the full name of the organization" or disease or whatever.  "origin" is a misnomer, except in "cute"  or "clever" acronyms.  Like M.A.D.D.

This could be one for ELU.

@TimR I would argue that there are worthwhile things to say about the history of "laser" since its invention.

@AndyBonner  That's not the question, as I understand it. The question assumes that determining the origin of acronyms is an area of "study" and I take issue with calling that effort "study".

@TimR Fair enough, but I read it then as "insofar as any given acronym has enough history to merit talking about the process of talking about that history... whaddaya call it?" And to my mind any acronym that got that far has earned the right to call it "etymology."

@AndyBonner  I take issue with "as any given acronym has enough history to merit talking about the process of talking about that history".  For some acronyms, sure (I referred to clever ones -- for example, RADAR) but for most, not.  What's worth discussing about the history of ESRD?

@TimR I think we're saying the same thing then, or pretty close. "Some acronyms don't support more than 30 seconds of 'study.' For those that do, what do we call that?" E.g. "Here's a book tracing the usage of the word 'radar,' from its birth in 1941 to its genericized figurative use e.g. 'on my radar.' That is, this book deals with the ___ of 'radar.'" And I'd say the answer is just "etymology." Mind you, this is a lot of talk without the OP chiming in; maybe they are misusing "acronym" and actually mean things like "Jul." for "July."

Although I think this question is answerable as-is, for better answers, please explain a bit about what sort of "acronyms" you're thinking of.

@AndyBonner Thanks, I should've written abbreviations to be more generic, as I don't know all the "subfields" that may stem from it and I find the foregoing discussion interesting. Btw, how to designate abbreviations that are neither acronyms or initialisms?

@AndyBonner You're extending the analysis well beyond the "origin of the acronym" into the history of the anacronym, the acronym-turned-word.  Acronyms don't have an etymology.  Anacronyms do. And of course not all acronyms become used like words.

I would use the word etymology, though for different reasons than @Colin Fine suggested.
Etymology, as you said, refers to the study of words and their, particularly historical, uses and evolutions. I would argue that acronyms are words and that the study of acronyms therefore falls under the umbrella of etymology.
Now if you want a more specific word for the sub-discipline of etymology concerned only with acronyms, I suspect you'll have to coin it (although I would be delighted to be shown to be wrong here).

Would you consider all acronyms to be words? What about  L1, A2, H1 or 1H? Are those words? The OP didn't mention that their question was inspired by their previous question Q1 2024 but 1H 2024. Why?

Etymology is the scientific study of the origin and evolution of a word's semantic meaning across time, including its constituent morphemes and phonemes In the rest of the article there is no mention of acronyms, or abbreviations

@Mari-LouA It's a "misuse" so common as to be not worth stickling about, but theoretically, "acronym" is supposed to be limited to initialisms that form new words (like "laser"). Things like "FBI" are just initialisms, and things like "L1" are just abbreviations.

@AndyBonner https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/354389/q1-2024-but-1h-2024-why#comment698492_354389 I'm not sure I'd call "L1" an abbreviation it is practically an initialism but in reverse, in my world it stands for "first language" i.e. mother tongue.

I would use etymology.
Note that the meaning of a word or phrase lies in how it is used. Dictionaries attempt to record this, but sometimes they lag behind reality.

Agreed. In this context acronym is simply a subset of words, and thus by extension we can talk about their origin or etymology.
